# How MySQL can auto generate a unique X length id when i insert a new value?

Tags: mysql

i want to create a `users` table where one of the values i will store on it, it will be a unique 8 digit `id` for each user. i want to automate this by making `MySQL` do it automatically every time i `insert` a new row.

how i can do what i asked for **without** starting to count from `0` and adding `1` every time i `insert` a new row?

```
CREATE TABLE users (id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id))
```

Comment: What's the reason for the IDs to be of exactly eight characters?

Comment: there is not a specific reason for `8` digits. it can be `9` or `6`, `12` or whatever, but i think `99.999.999` is a good limit when it comes to user id's. if you got confused about the `8`, forget it and focus on "`X length id`".

Comment: If there's no reason for it, there's also no reason to just simply go with an `integer AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: Well, just consider not to make things more complicated as they need to be for no reason...

Comment: The problem with random numbers a primary keys is they generate [horrible performance](https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/04/03/illustrating-primary-key-models-in-innodb-and-their-impact-on-disk-usage/). When you ask a question, listen to the answers, particularly the ones you don't want to. Understanding the objective enables a broader range of potentially better answers.

Comment: its not that big of difference to be `8` instead of `1`. there is any way to do what i asked for?

Comment: so you suggest me to just use `integer AUTO_INCREMENT` if isn't any serious reason for wanting to use `8` digits?

Comment: would you happen to be using a server side language? is it an option to generate the number that way and use it as a parameter to the insert queries?